# Using a variable inside a selector for querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, iteration, nightwatch.js

I'm programming a unit testing script with Nightwatch and I'm attempting to iterate through any 'a' tags contained within several child elements on a page. I'm trying to use querySelectorAll to get the number of 'a' tags within each child, but the statement doesn't seem to work when I introduce an iterating variable to the selector.

The following function is being called within a for loop, with the x variable being passed:

```
browser.execute(function() {
    return document.querySelectorAll("div.field-item.even *:not(a):nth-child(" + x + ") a").length;
},
    function(links){
        a_total = links.value;
        console.log("a total: " + links.value);
});
```

The x variable in this context should be 1, but this is what the code returns regardless of what x is equal to:

```
a total: [object Object]
```

I'm not sure why it's returning an object when it should be returning a number. It also strangely seems to work if I swap out my x variable for a static number. For example,

```
return document.querySelectorAll("div.field-item.even *:not(a):nth-child(1) a").length;
```

gives me the following:

```
a total: 2
```

I'm not sure why the selector returns an object. I thought that the selector was just a string. Why doesn't it seem to work when I put a variable into the selector string?

Comment: how/where is that `x` defined? have you tried doing a `console.log(x)` in there to see what it really is?

Comment: x should be defined in a for loop outside the function call and then passed into the function where I'm running the execute command, but I can't seem to get it working no matter where I define x. For simplicity, I defined it just outside of my browser.execute function as var x=1. If I use console.log to print x in the same spot I am printing the a_total, it appears to be the correct value, but I still get [object Object] for the a_total.

Comment: `console.log(links.value)`, then, and see what's in this object.

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't know you could print out the object. I think I figured it out. It looks like x was not defined within the execute statement because I didn't pass x to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem was because I did not pass x to the .execute function. I found a [GitHub topic on the issue](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/353).

The following code seems to work:

```
browser.execute(function(x) {
    return document.querySelectorAll("div.field-item.even *:not(a):nth-child(" + x + ") a").length;
}, [x],
function(links){
    console.log("a total: " + links.value);
});
```